# Scala. Generic class declaration trouble

Tags: scala, user-defined-functions, generic-programming

I have a trouble with class declaration in Scala:

```
   class Class2[
      A,
      B <: Class2[A,B,C],
      C <: Class3[A,C]
   ]


   class Class3[
      A,
      C <: Class3[A,C]
   ]

   class Class1[
      A, 
      B <: Class2[A,B,C], 
      C <: Class3[A,C]
    ](obj : B) { ... }
```

It is correct declaration, but every time I want to create an instance of that class I need to specify parameters A and C by hand. Like:

```
val X = Class1[Type1, Type2, Type3](correct_object_of_Type2)
```

If I try `val X = Class1(OBJ)` it will lead to error `...types [Nothing, B, Nothing] do not conform to [A, B, C]...`

Why doesn't Scala infer types A and C from B? And how to declare class for a Scala compiler so that it will be able to specify A, C by itself? Thanks

**EDIT**

I'm sorry for formulation, the original task is to correctly define Class1 like:

```
   class Class2[
      A,
      B <: Class2[A,B,C],
      C <: Class3[A,C]
   ]


   class Class3[
      A,
      C <: Class2[A,C]
   ]

   ??class Class1(obj : Class2) { ... }??
```

... so that it will be correct to call `val x = Class1(obj)`, where `obj: Class2`. When I try to define it as above, I'm getting error `Class2 takes type parameters`. Any ideas?

Sorry for inaccuracy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's possible to have the type parameters inferred by encoding the constraints as implicit parameters:

```
class Class2[X, Y, Z]
class Class3[X, y]

class Class1[A, B, C](obj: B)(implicit
  evB: B <:< Class2[A, B, C],
  evC: C <:< Class3[A, C]
)
```

And then:

```
scala> class Foo extends Class3[String, Foo]
defined class Foo

scala> class Bar extends Class2[String, Bar, Foo]
defined class Bar

scala> new Class1(new Bar)
res0: Class1[String,Bar,Foo] = Class1@ff5b51f
```

If you need to use instances of `B` or `C` as `Class2[A, B, C]` or `Class3[A, C]` in the definition of `Class1`, you can apply the appropriate evidence parameter (`evB` or `evC`) to them.

Your version doesn't work because Scala's type inference system is very limited. It will first solve for `A` and end up at `Nothing`, since the argument to the constructor doesn't have an `A` in it. Next it will try to solve for `B` and not be able to find a value that satisfies the constraint, since it's already decided `A` is `Nothing`.

So you have to decide whether type inference is worth an extra bit of complexity and runtime overhead. Sometimes it is, but in my experience when you have classes like this with relationships that are already fairly complex, it's usually not.

Comment: Thanks for answer, it works! but I understoot that I didn't write all details of trouble. I'm sorry. Check 'Edit' please